# How disable the apm on DEV enviroment

Tags: javascript, node.js, elastic-stack, package.json, apm

I have a application with the apm enabled and the unique reference to the apm sdk is on the package.json dependencies and at the app.js. whose i have the line below:

```
const apm = require('elastic-apm-node').start()
```

The constant 'apm' does not utilized at nowhere.

I want to remove the apm because in my local environment i receive the below messages:

```
APM Server transport error (503): Unexpected APM Server response
queue is full
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the `ELASTIC_APM_ACTIVE` env var to `false`? Refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/master/configuration.html#active

Comment: It works! But now it is not showing the error messages on the console. How do i it?

Comment: There's also `ELASTIC_APM_LOG_LEVEL` where you can set to `info` as a start. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/master/configuration.html#log-level

Comment: Perfect. It works. Thank you @mrkre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the environment variable `ELASTIC_APM_ACTIVE` to `false`.

Refer to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/nodejs/master/configuration.html#active.

Answer (score 2):

At the start of the `server.js` add the following code and for production, you can export NODE_ENV to `production`

```
require("elastic-apm-node").start({
    serviceName: "AppName",
    secretToken: "",
    serverUrl: "URL",
    captureBody: "errors",
    active: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
});
```